# WordPress form submission issue

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

Hello everyone and thanks for looking! I have an issue on my page where two forms exist,  when you fill in just the bottom form, it prompts you to enter the fields from the first form as well. Is there a way to fix this? I have been trying to fix this all day without any luck.

The issue is happening in the "Remote Collector Update" form.

This is the page: https://www.device42.com/update-cadence-test
pass: 123

I have tried removing all sorts of ids and classes but nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="f_email" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email f_email field_error_txt" name="email-618" size="40" type="email" value="" placeholder="Work Email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">


<input id="f_email" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-email wpcf7-validates-as-required wpcf7-validates-as-email f_email" name="email-618" size="40" type="email" value="" placeholder="Work Email" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false">
```

Could there be a name conflict at validation time?

Maybe you could try changing the name in form one to email-617 and give it a try. Two elements sharing the same ID could also cause validation errors.